# Is there a way to determine via registry .NET Core version with NSIS?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nsis

I need to create a setup file using NSIS. Part of the process is to check the Net Core version. Basing this on the registry entry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET Core\Shared Framework`  I have the following

```
  ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET Core\Shared Framework" "v6.0" 
  StrCmp $0 0 Net6 NoNet6
NoNet6:
  MessageBox MB_OK ".NET 6.0 or later version was not found! [$0]"
  Abort
Net6:
    MessageBox MB_OK ".NET 6.0 or later version was found! [$0]"
```

This does not work. What I would like to do is check to see if the subfolder "v6.0" exists, this way I would know that core version 6 exists. If it doesn't then I can pop a message and abort the setup.

Is there a way to compare the name of the subfolder to "v6.0"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you not able to run `dotnet --info` with NSIS?

Comment: @Crowcoder - I can, but I dont know how to filter the information in order to see if the version exists so I am trying the registry route.

Answer (score 2):

You can see all runtimes/sdk installed here. Though you should probably use something like dotnet --version, or dotnet --info

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedhost
```

it will show you this:

[image]

Here is some C# to read the value.

```
var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedhost\");
           
var version = key.GetValue("Version").Dump();
```

NSIS - `ReadRegStr $3 HKLM "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedhost\" "Version"`

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I cant get NSIS to read Version...

Comment: I updated code with C# and NSIS example. Try one of those.

Comment: The registry subkey is wrong in the last code example...

Comment: @mathis1337 - your registry was part of the solution.  I needed the SetRegView to be set to 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem besides my registry entry was how NSIS gets information.  I had to set the registry view to 64bit.

```
  ; check for .NET 6 properly installed
  SetRegView 64
  ReadRegStr $0 HKLM SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedhost Version
  IntCmp $0 6 Net6 NoNet6 Net6
NoNet6:
  MessageBox MB_OK ".NET 6.0 or later version was NOT found! [$0]"
  Abort
Net6:
  MessageBox MB_OK ".NET 6.0 or later version was found! [$0]"
```

Thanks to Mathis1337 for the registry entry suggestion.  Adding the "SetRegView 64" got it working.